# Error 500 when including/requiring src/facebook.php from Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working to implement a Facebook login for my website. I have limited knowledge of php debugging so I'm more or less looking for a good approach to debug this.

As soon as I include (or require) the `facebook.php` file, with no other SDK interaction, Apache will 500 my PHP script.

```
include('fb-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
```

`fb-php-sdk` is a directory within the directory that contains our PHP script (also the document root)

---

Server log:

```
[Tue Nov 15 23:18:16 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.110] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.'

in /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php:19\nStack trace:

#0 /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/facebook.php(18): require_once()
#1 /var/www/index.php(13): include('/var/www/fb-php...')
#2 {main} thrown in /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 19 

From /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: can you paste your php_error_log?

Comment: [Tue Nov 15 23:18:16 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.110] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.' in /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/facebook.php(18): require_once()\n#1 /var/www/index.php(13): include('/var/www/fb-php...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/fb-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 19

Install CURL =)

From /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: the package name to be installed is php5-curl for anybody else with this issue. won't let me close my own problem until 8 hours have passed.

Comment: I suggsest you turn on your error reporting (while developing), you'll save yourself a lot of hassle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install CURL =)

Command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Comment: After that you could have to add on `php.ini` the line `extension=php_curl.so` to enable CURL and then restart Apache.